# How to assign state variables to style component in react native?

Tags: react-native

With react.js it's possible to assign a state variable to a div or any other element like so :

```
<div className={this.state.test}>
```

With react native I cannot see how to implement the same logic :

```
<Image style={this.state.test} />
```

> The test variable in this example = 'styles.custom'

Comment: Typically, styles are kept out of state. The convention is to declare a StyleSheet object as a const outside of the component.

Comment: I think your isssue may be what is contained in the `styles.custom` can you should more detail as to how you are setting them? Perhaps show a sample component where you are trying to use this?

Answer (score 0):

The outer curly braces mean it's js and the inner brackets means it a style object, so you need double curly braces

```
  <Image style={{this.state.test}} />
```

Comment: I tried this before posting the question, error is 'this' is a reserved word

Comment: this would be work <Image style={this.state.test} />

Answer (score 0):

```
//imports
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    width: 64 //random property
  }
  render() {
   return <Image source={...} style={[styles.button, {...this.state}]}>
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create{
 button: {
  height: 64
 }
}
```

Comment: This will work for maybe one or two props, I have too many so not that convenient, thanks tho